# SQL JOIN return joined data as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I try to make some nice structure data for frontend on my server side.

**Response should looks like:**

```
    [
      {
        "id": "57484a7e0cdb86d125ebce9c",
        "wasCalled": true,
        "wasGood": false,
        "candidateName": "Tonia Santos",
        "positions": [
          {
            "positionId": "48asd4asd36",
            "positionName": "Pozicia1"
          },
          {
            "positionId": "954asd5as4d",
            "positionName": "Pozicia4"
          }
        ],
        "addedBy": "User1",
        "registered": "2014-11-30T07:13:27 -01:00"
      }
  ]
```

**Database structure:**

- candidates: All info exept positions

  | id | wasCalled | wasGood | addedBy | firstName | lastName
- candidates_positions: Each row is one user and one position

  | id  | candidateId | positionId | positionName

**How I try it:**

```
class getCandidates
{
    public function getFromDatabase(){
        try {
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidates as c INNER JOIN candidates_positions as cp ON c.id=cp.candidateId;";
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

    public function createJson($data){
        return json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

**What it actually create:**

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "Tonia",
    "lastName": "Santos",
    "addedBy": "22",
    "wasCalled": "1",
    "wasGood": null,
    "candidateId": "1",
    "positionId": "1",
    "positionName": "Pozicia4"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "Tonia",
    "lastName": "Santos",
    "addedBy": "22",
    "wasCalled": "1",
    "wasGood": null,
    "candidateId": "1",
    "positionId": "1",
    "positionName": "Pozicia1"
}]
```

Is there some nice way or best practice how to create JSON similar as on TOP of this question without making multiple selects on database and building JSON?

Thanks for any advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you get multiple rows for the same people, containing different positions, it might look like (typing out of my head so may be some error there, but try it out and see):

```
 function prepare_result($data) {
  $result = [];
  foreach ($data as $record) {
    if (!isset($result[$record['candidateId']])) {
      $result[$record['candidateId']] = array(
        'id' => (int) $record['candidateId'],
        'wasCalled' => true,
        'wasGood' => false,
        'candidateName' => $record['firstName'] . " " . $record['lastName'],
        'addedBy' => 'no idea', // you need additional join i think, since your result returns only ID
        'registered' => 'no idea either', // same as above, original query returns no date
        'positions' => array(
          array(
            'positionId' => $record['positionId'],
            'positionName' => $record['positionName']
          )
        )
      );
    } else {
      $result[$record['candidateId']]['positions'][] = array(
        'positionId' => $record['positionId'],
        'positionName' => $record['positionName']
      );
    }
  }

  sort($result);

  return json_encode($result);
}
```

Note the comments for `registered` and `addedBy`.

Comment: Hi @Oliver, I think you are close but this will not return array of objects. 
Example JSON will looks like: http://pastebin.com/7rFJ45ma

Comment: @Andurit well, it is an array of objects as far as I can see, but I did mess up appending positions and I've updated that bit (code updated in the answer)

Answer (score 2):

Enough though your issue is resolved but do take a look at the following answer, it's more neat and concise.

### Answer:

Make use of MySQL's `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` clauses, and subsequently change your query like this,

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.positionId, '|', cp.positionName) as positions 
FROM candidates as c 
INNER JOIN candidates_positions as cp 
ON c.id=cp.candidateId 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Here are the references:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

So just change the `getFromDatabase()` method in the following way,

```
public function getFromDatabase(){
    try {
        $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $sql = "SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.positionId, '|', cp.positionName) as positions FROM candidates as c INNER JOIN candidates_positions as cp ON c.id=cp.candidateId GROUP BY c.id";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result_arr = array();
        while($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $tmp_arr = array('id' => $result['id'], 'wasCalled' => $result['wasCalled'], 'wasGood' => $result['wasGood'], 'addedBy' => $result['addedBy'], 'firstName' => $result['firstName'], 'lastName' => $result['lastName']);
            $positions = explode(",", $result['positions']);
            foreach($positions as $s){
                $components = explode("|", $s);
                $tmp_arr['positions'][] = array('positionId' => $components[0], 'positionName' => $components[1]);
            }
            $result_arr[] = $tmp_arr;
        }
        return $result_arr;
    }catch( PDOException $e ) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Later, you can pass the returned `$result_arr` array to `createJson()` method and apply `json_encode` on it.

Comment: Hey mate, thank you for your answer. I already thumb up and will think about this. For me as someone who can consider him self as beginer this looks more clean than previous answer. Thanks for this !

Comment: why on earth would you use `group_concat` there, and concatenating with a space? the code will fall apart if the position has a space character in it. or, if `group_concat()` is using whatever, anyway: you cannot be sure that what you choose to pass as concat string will not be present as position's name, therefore ruining the logic that `explode()` is supposed to perform.

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic [1/2] 1) *why on earth would you use group_concat...*? Because it makes the code more concise and visualisable, and it makes the manipulation much easier. Besides why shouldn't you? 2) *the code will fall apart if the position has a space character in it...*? According to OP's sample json string, there's **no space** in *positionName* and I kept that thing in mind while writing this answer. However, you could be right. Assuming the fact that *positionName* might have a space in there somewhere, I've further updated my answer(Instead of space, I've added a pipe character to...

Comment: @OliverMaksimovic [2/2] ...separate <positionId,positionName> pairs). Now it should fine in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse your result and get the desired result by changing you createJson method

```
    public function createJson($data){
        return_array = array();
        foreach($data as $val)
        {
          $return_array['id']= $val['id'];
          $return_array['candidateName']= $val['candidateName'];
          $return_array['wasCalled']= $val['wasCalled'];
          $return_array['wasGood']= $val['wasGood'];
          $return_array['addedBy']= $val['addedBy'];
          $return_array['positions'][] = array('positionId'=> $val['positionId'],'positionName'=>$val['positionName']);
        }
        return json_encode($return_array);
    }
```

Comment: it's not a good array, since the database returns a record for each position

Comment: Hi @theDeceptio thank you for your answer. I afriad this not work correctly, it create array of objects but instead of return 2 candidates where 1th have 2 positions and 2th have 1 position it return something likehttp://pastebin.com/WdZcUhYh

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your query
I should use

`select ID, if (wasCalled=1,true,false) as wasCalled, if (wasGood=1,true,false) as wasGood,`

```
concat(firstName,' ',lastName) as candidateName, positionID, positionName,addedBy
```

By the way this is only a partial solution and you have combine this one with theDeceptio's answer to get your final solution.
This is necessary because you don't have a candidateName field and you have to create.
Furthermore, please note that your addedBy returns an ID and you want the name tied to that ID, so I infer that you have some other tables where you must extract this info